# How log the different message to the different files for LoggerFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, lombok

I want to log the different message to the different files.log. I want to use filename from application.properties without xml. How to indicate properties for an instance of LoggerFactory or slf4j ?

For example,

I have the next properties in my application.properties file:

```
logging.level.root=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR
logging.level.com.project=INFO
logging.level.com.project.service=INFO
# Logging pattern for the console
logging.pattern.console="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n"
# Logging pattern for file
logging.pattern.file="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
logging.file.name=log/project.log
```

I use @Slf4j from lombok and 'log' property as default for printing my message. But I want to use some more files for printing  specific logs.

Comment: what do you mean by "printing specific logs"? Do you want to log different LOG levels to different files? INFO to info.log, ERROR to error.log etc..?

Comment: @MohdWaseem I meen that I want to save the content different message into the different files. For example, statuses or specific metrics...